# Mass setting prices according to taxonomy term in the Ubercart

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, taxonomy, product, ubercart

I need mass setting prices according to taxonomy terms in the Ubercart. So when I add product 'xyz' to 'Hello' taxonomy term which has 10$ this product will be 10$. Thanks for help M.

Comment: Where is the question ?. "I need xyz.", seems for me to be an affirmation not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a [View](http://drupal.org/project/views), and use [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module to do this manually. 
If you want to automate this, use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module. It's difficult to tell the exact way, nor your question is much clear. To my experience so far, there is no out-of-the-box way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, you right, this is not in Ubercart out of box, but my client want to solution based on taxonomy terms. So instead filling  of price field at product edit page he want use setting price on taxonomy terms (when product 'XYZ' is add to taxonomy term 'hello world', this product would inherit price from this term)

Comment: Can I ask at do you know how to create advertisement system where will be taxonomy terms (sections) only for pay? Ex. when a user create "ad node" then he add this one to terms (ex. 5) and for every term he pay (payment per term). Sorry for my english. thanks M.

Comment: I looked only "Classified Ads" module that has problem because it allow use only one content type (I red this in the [queue issue](http://drupal.org/node/350938) of that module). I will look to Advertisement. Thanks